# Custom accessor method in Core Data, why using KVO?

Tags: ios, core-data, key-value-observing, accessor, kvc

A typical custom accessor method could be written as the following:

```
- (NSString *)name
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *myName = [self primitiveName];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    return myName;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveName:newName];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

It's clear the meaning of `setPrimitiveName`. It allows you to access the "raw " variable without KVC (preventing a run loop inside the accessor) and set the value passed in. The same observation can be applied to the getter.

From the documentation it's clear that `setPrimitiveName` disables change notifications methods: `willChangeValueForKey` and counterpart.

Now my question is the following: why do you need to wrap that method inside `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` methods?

Reading the Core Data programming there is written that:

> NSManagedObject disables automatic key-value observing (KVO) change
>   notifications for modeled properties, and the primitive accessor
>   methods do not invoke the access and change notification methods. For
>   unmodeled properties, on Mac OS X v10.4 Core Data also disables
>   automatic KVO; on Mac OS X v10.5 and later, Core Data adopts to
>   NSObject’s behavior.

Why do I need to inform that I'm ready to access a key (accessor or instance variable) and then I've done with it? Who is informed?

Hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need it to inform the view,that your value has changed.
Let' take for example, that you would use **MKMapView** and put some annotations on it, taking coordinates from Core Data, and then, somehow, you change it's location.

If you getter/setter didn't post these notifications, **MKMapView** wouldn't know of these changes in locations, and wouldn't move it to the new one.

You can also track the date of creation/change of your objects with these notifications.

I guess, that redo/undo is also made by this.

## NOTE

I would like to know, if Core Data uses these notifications somehow under the hood. Does anybody has any ideas on this subject?

Comment: +1 for your support. Is this needed to inform only views or something else is involved?

Comment: That's the examples I found so far,but,maybe there is something even more interesting)

Comment: Yes, Core Data uses them to know when to fire faults and to populate the object.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. But isn't it used for undo/redo tracking in Core Data too?(Just my guess)